# php Notice: Undefined offset: 0 when it shouldn't actually occur

Tags: php, preg-match, offset

However it does print it for me. So it does return correctly but places the error at the `preg_match('%">(.+?)</p>%s', $resultsDescription[$i][0], $resultsDescriptionFinal[$i]);`. What might be wrong here?

```
$resultsCount = sizeof($results[0]);
    if($resultsCount > 5)
    {
        $resultsCount = 5;
    }
    $resultsCountForLoop = ($resultsCount - 1);


    for ( $i = 0; $i <= $resultsCountForLoop; $i++ ) {
        preg_match('%title="(.+?)\"%s', $results[0][$i], $resultsTitle[$i]);
        preg_match('%href="(.+?)"%s', $results[0][$i], $resultsLink[$i]);
        preg_match('%<img src="(.+?)"%s', $results[0][$i], $resultsImage[$i]);
        $getImageAndDescription[$i] = file_get_contents($rootURLToGetContents.$resultsLink[$i][1]);
        preg_match('%id="plot(.+?)<\/p>%s', $getimageAndDescription[$i], $resultsDescription[$i]);
        if (isset($resultsDescription[$i])){
        preg_match('%">(.+?)<\/p>%s', $resultsDescription[$i][0], $resultsDescriptionFinal[$i]);
        }

    //print_r($resultsLink[$i]);
    //echo $i;
    }

    print_r($resultsLink[0]);
    print_r($resultsImage[0]);
    print_r($resultsTitle[0]);
    print_r($resultsDescriptionFinal[0];




    and the error that I get is <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\library\s\results.php on line <i>27</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0063</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>690024</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\library\s\results.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\results.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    </table></font>
```

Comment: `var_dump($results)` and the complete error message please, otherwise it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: `var_dump($resultsDescription)` would be useful too

Comment: gees thanks so much for replying, that is the whole error message though, and to dump the results is a really large array of books... however the cover image and description are in two different pages.

Comment: the error occurs when after getting the href for the description which is on the same landing page as the image i do a file_get_contents for each of the results of the books title, and then do a preg match to get the description. Thats where the error occurs!

Comment: the error is thrown for the following line

Comment: preg_match('%">(.+?)<\/p>%s', $resultsDescription[$i][0], $resultsDescriptionFinal[$i]);

Comment: but it cant be. if after the for loop i do echo preg_match('%">(.+?)<\/p>%s', $resultsDescription[0][0], $resultsDescriptionFinal[0]); I dont get an error the error is undefined offset 0

Comment: the iterator is set at zero, so echoing $resultsDescriptionFinal[0]; setting it the way above after the loop should be the same as within it! am I wrong? ive been searching incessantly!! hope you can help!

Comment: Fyi, `$resultsCountForLoop = ($resultsCount - 1);` is extremely ugly. Why don't you just use `$i < $resultsCount` in your loop condition?

Comment: hahahahahhahahahaha i guess I could use $i < ($resultsCount - 1) but i need the -1 othwize it goes one over and throws an offset error at the end as well!

Comment: i was laughing at the ugly part hahhaha

Comment: I guess I should say that result description returns the following

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => id="description_289186">The Wealth of Nations by Adam Smith is considered the first real study of the social science we now call Economics...</p>
    [1] => _289186">The Wealth of Nations by Adam Smith is considered the first real study of the social science we now call Economics...
)

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8265673/edit), don't add all relevant information as comments. (Then delete the comments). Also, you still didn't show the **actual notice / error message**, nor the `var_dump($resultsDescription)` as asked about. Your problem is an uninitialized subarray. And that's it.

Comment: ok! sorry this is the first time i posted a question, im usually just reading them! ill do a var_dump($resultsDescription)!

Comment: ok the dump is too long, but your right! not all of them are returning with descriptions, and thats the problem. so its not at $resultsDescriptionFinal[0] but rather at $resultsDescriptionFinal[2]! is there any way of fixing this? i would have thought that the if (isset($resultsDescription[$i])) line would have taken care of that. im sorry is my question terrible.

Comment: And last but not least, there is also a PHP operator to have the display of (provably *insignificant*) notices suppressed in the default error handler. But we're not allowed to mention it here sans lengthy tutoring and apologies. [So I won't.](http://php.net/@)

Answer (score 1):

```
    preg_match('%">(.+?)<\/p>%s', $resultsDescription[$i][0], $resultsDescriptionFinal[$i]);
```

The notice comes either from a missing `$resultsDescription[$i][0]` or an empty `$resultsDescriptionFinal[$i]`, obviously.

Reformat your code like this to get a conclusive pointer:

```
    preg_match(
         '%">(.+?)<\/p>%s',
         $resultsDescription[$i][0],
         $resultsDescriptionFinal[$i]
    );
```

And then either initialize the missing vars, or probe them beforehand, or start using less fiddly array nesting. For the second parameter to `preg_match` it's very customary to supply a simple generic `$matches` variable.
Then you could still assign its results (if any) to your nested array *afterwards*:

```
    preg_match('%">(.+?)<\/p>%s', $match, $src);
    $resultsDescription[$i][0] = $match;
```

Likewise you can use `isset($resultsDescriptionFinal[$i])` before that to check if the `$src` text is actually available.

Comment: gees thanks a tone!!!! thank you thank you! im on my way! and happy thanksgiving!!!!

Comment: ok well again thanks a tone! the answer is to check if (isset($resultsDescription[$i][0] because $resultsDescription[$i] was set but it had nothing in it! i wouldnt have seen that withoutyou though, and i kept searching and searching for a clue! thanks so much!